# Uniquely identify user in Microsoft Bot Framework Web Chat

Tags: botframework

I want to uniquely identify users in Web Chat and store information particular to the user.

As far as I know Web Chat does not support channel data, so is there any way to identify users?

Can anyone help me on this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [activity](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/a71e64c24bd40f8b99de0a3326ea1b79110c33e1/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Shared/IActivity.cs#L9) that your bot receives and send contains a [From](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/a71e64c24bd40f8b99de0a3326ea1b79110c33e1/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Shared/IActivity.cs#L44) and a [Recipient](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/a71e64c24bd40f8b99de0a3326ea1b79110c33e1/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Shared/IActivity.cs#L54) property that you can inspect to get details about the user, including the [Id](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/3a98a6b3d15962a57b5454bfb3f730d3588de3ef/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Shared/ConnectorAPI/Models/ChannelAccount.cs#L38).